# Mediaelement.js javascript error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js as my HTML5 video player for a site in progress. It works fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, even with the fallback player, but in Internet Explorer I get the Javascript error seen here: http://d.pr/Jsfo. It doesn't seem to be loading my poster, or my player style (which works fine in the other browsers).

The player's code is being loaded dynamically, because it appears in a lightbox and there are multiple videos that can be played on the page. The Javascript that injects the HTML is at the bottom of the page

You can see the development site live at http://mindsmack.ryangiglio.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't dynamically insert HTML5 tags in IE because it breaks their nesting

```
<video>
   <source src="file.mp4">
   <source src="file.webm">
</video>
```

becomes

```
<video />
<source src="file.mp4">
<source src="file.webm">
```

And then MediaElement.js can't figure out where the source files are.

My recommendation would be to put a `<video>` tag in a permanent spot on the page, then prepare a MediaElement object

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video');
```

and then when you're ready to play a video, just call it

```
// single MP4
player.setSrc('newfile.mp4');

// OR multiple
player.setSrc([{src:'newfile.mp4',type:'video/mp3'},{src:'newfile.webm',type:'video/webm'}]);

// load and play
player.load();
player.play();
```

Also, you should remove the `<object>` embed HTML inside the `<video>` tag since that's only for cases when IE users don't have JavaScript enabled, and your app requires JavaScript.

Comment: I forgot about that HTML5 IE error. There's actually an excellent little piece of Javascript that remedies that problem: http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/. That fixed it without changing any code other than adding the function call.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll make sure to point other people to that if they are doing something similar.